# Is there a PYTHON data structure with O(log n) deletion/insertion and supports indexing?

Tags: python

While doing competitive coding, I came across a scenario where I needed O(log n) removal, while being able to support indexing (O(1) preferably) for a binary search. I essentially need to locate an element using a binary approach (currently using bisect), and then remove that element I found, which is currently a O(n) operation. I obviously cannot use libraries that are not built in, hence why blist is not an option, and I can't use a set because that doesn't support indexing. Is there an alternative, or is using something like a binary tree the only option. If so, are there any easy pre-defined libraries in python that I am able to use?

Comment: Consider, perhaps, a [treap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treap). You will have to build it yourself, I think.

Comment: Do you need indexing or binary search? Because if you just need search then any balanced search tree would do (no idea if python have some as part of standard library, but you can search yourself for red-black tree or AVL tree in python and have code ready to copy-paste)

Comment: A skip list or even an AA tree is probably easier to implement than a red-black tree.

Comment: You can probably get adequate performance in Python even for largish (1e7) lists with just two layers. No need for a full tree. http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/implementation.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python does not appear to have such a structure in the standard library.

I'm not exactly sure of your needs, but since you considered using a set, that means you don't need duplicate items. Consider not changing the length of the list for a delete. Instead, replace the element you want to remove with its next-highest (non-equal) neighbor to the right. (If it happens to be the last element, you can just pop it.) The length and general indexing will be wrong, but a binary search will still work, which might be all that you need the indexing for.

Say you have `[0,1,2,3,4,5]` and you want to remove the `3`. Make the list `[0,1,2,4,4,5]`. If you then want to remove the `4`, make it `[0,1,2,5,5,5]`.

You can use a binary search to find both ends of the run, which gives you the O(log n) removal you want. Use `bisect_left` first, and then pass in the answer from that to restrict the part of the list searched by `bisect_right`. Once you know the bounds, Python can assign the whole slice at once.

If you then want to remove the `5`, pop them off `[0,1,2]`. Removal at the end of the list is more efficient since it won't require allocating a new array.

You can clean up the duplicates occasionally for better amortized performance, or if you need the length or something. Maybe when the number of "deletions" reaches a certain fraction of the original length. Don't go through a `set`, because you'd have to sort again. (`OrderedDict.fromkeys` could work, but you'd still have to build a list from the `.keys()`). Just copy the list while skipping over the duplicates, like

```
itr = iter(old)
new = [next(itr)]
for e in itr:
    if e is not new[-1]:
        new.append(e)
```